# Combining objects across a list

Tags: r, list, coding-style, statistics, random-forest

I have a simple question. I have a list of objects. Each object holds a few lists. Before this gets too complicated, let me illustrate:

> x = a list
>
> x[[1]] = some object
>
> x[[2]] = another object
>
> ...
>
> x[[n]] = another object

And as I said, each object holds some more lists. But I'm interested in a specific list, let's call it "a".

> x[[1]][[a]] = ('A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, ..., Z: 26)

Sorry for the python-like syntax! I am really just learning R. Anyway, what I want to do is combine the lists held in these objects, then take their median. To make this more clear, I want to group all 'A' elements, then take their median:

> x[[1]][[a]][['A']], x[[2]][[a]][['A']], x[[3]][[a]][['A']], ..., x[[n]][[a]][['A']]

Similarly I want to group all 'B', 'C', ..., 'Z' elements and take their median...

> x[[1]][[a]][['Z']], x[[2]][[a]][['Z']], x[[3]][[a]][['Z']], ..., x[[n]][[a]][['Z']]

So the question is what's the best way to do this? I've spent hours trying to figure this out! It would be great if someone could help me.

And if you would like to know what I'm actually doing, basically I have a list (x) of random forest objects. So x[[1]] is the first random forest, x[[100]] is the 100th random forest. Each random forest has a list of predicted values, which are stored in, e.g. x[[1]][['predicted']]. Each prediction list has a label associated with its predicted value. What I'm actually trying to do is calculate each label's median predicted value across all 100 random forests. And I want to do it efficiently. In Python, this is easy, but in R I'm not so sure. Anyway, thanks for the help!!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Use something like `lapply(yourList, "[", "predicted")`

Comment: Thanks Andrie! At first, this wasn't working, but I eventually got something similar to work: sapply(list, function(y) y[['predicted']]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it. It's a bit tough because you can't use `rapply` to subset by the names of list elements (which is frustrating). But you can unlist and then subset on names and take the `median` that way...

```
# Make some reproducible data
set.seed(1)
l <- list( a = sample(10,3) , b = sample(10,3) , c = sample(10,3) )
ll <- list( l , l , l )

# Unlist - we get a named vector but all a's have unique names - e.g. a1 , a2... an
unl <- unlist(ll)
# a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 
#  3  4  5 10  2  8 10  6  9  3  4  5 10  2  8 10  6  9  3  4  5 10  2  8 10  6  9

# Subset by those elements that contian 'a' in their name
a.unl <- unl[ grepl("a",names(unl)) ]
# a1 a2 a3 a1 a2 a3 a1 a2 a3 
#  3  4  5  3  4  5  3  4  5 

#  Take median
median( a.unl )
# [1] 4
```

To loop over multiple names try this...

```
sapply( c( "a" , "b" , "c" ) , function(x) median( unl[ grepl(x,names(unl) ) ] ) )
# a b c 
# 4 8 9
```

Comment: @ab a `for` loop isn't really elegant (IMHO). It's usually slow. Try the edit.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely works. Another solution is to use sapply (above)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with a simple loop for every A,B,C,...

```
x <- c()
for( i in 1:n ) x <- c( x, x[[i]][[a]][['A']] )
median(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data for creating your top-level list `x`:

```
x <- replicate(3, list(a = as.list(setNames(sample(1:100, 26), LETTERS)),
                       b = runif(10)),
               simplify = FALSE)
```

First, extract `a` from each list:

```
a.only <- lapply(ll, `[[`, "a")
```

Then, to compute all `A` through `Z` medians in one shot, do:

```
do.call(mapply, c(a.only, FUN = function(...) median(unlist(list(...)))))
#  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z 
# 55 59 41 21 93 72 65 74 51 42 87 25 60 40 13 77 35 31 92 51 57 37 87 67 29 46
```

If the sublists contain more items than you need, say you only want to compute medians on `A`, `C`, `Z`, do:

```
a.slices <- lapply(a.only, `[`, c("A", "C", "Z"))
do.call(mapply, c(a.slices, FUN = function(...) median(unlist(list(...)))))
#  A  C  Z 
# 55 41 46
```